# Trying to create a script for trigger mail based on a condition in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So this is the script am using, it sends out a blank mail without any content in them. Here I am trying to compare two columns and if the value in one column is great am trying to add the row header to the list which has to be sent out via mail. Can someone help me out pls.

```
function Mailer1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");    
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Today");  
var values = sheet.getRange("AD2:AD").getValues();
var value1s = sheet.getRange("AE2:AE").getValues();
var results = [];
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
{
  if(values[i]>value1s[i])
  {
     var value5 = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).getValue();
     results.concat(value5);
  }
}
MailApp.sendEmail('vinay_narayanan@playshifu.com','Restock Needed At:',results);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the values in 30 and 31 are some sort of quantities and the value in column 1 is a date.

Try doing this:

```
function Mailer1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Today");
  var values = sh.getRange(2, 30, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  var value1s = sh.getRange(2, 31, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] > value1s[i]) {
      results.push(sh.getRange(i + 2, 1).getValue());
    }
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail('vinay_narayanan@playshifu.com', 'Restock Needed At:', results.join('\n'));
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Can you also tell me how to update it so that I can send out the same mail to multiple recipients instead of just 1. 
Sorry am a total amateur at this!

Comment: provide the receipient parameter with a comma separated list of emails